# <python novice> comparing record counts of multiple tables queried from different databases using python

Tags: python, sql

I have two methods to query two different databases with multiple tables and I need to compare only the record count retrieved. Any way where I don't need to export results in files first and then compare using pandas? What is the best way to do this scenario?

I think we need to create an empty list and then add for loop to append each table, but how will it append record count with each table ?

Created a dummy code below:

```
table_list = ['tableA', 'tableB', 'tableC', 'tableD']

def database_1(conn, table_list):
    list1 = []
    for table in table_list:
        sql = "select count(*) from tableA where date='today'"
        exec = conn.cursor.execute(sql)
        result = exec.fetchone()
        count1 = result[0]
        add = list1.append(count1)       
    return list1


def database_2(conx, table_list):
    list2= []
    for table in table_list:
        sql = "select count(*) from tableA where date='today'"
        exec = conx.cursor.execute(sql)
        result = exec.fetchone()
        count2 = result[0]
        add = list2.append(count2)
    return list2

def call_both():
    "compare the record counts from both for each table and log details of the comparison, not sure what to do here"
    if database1(conn, table_list) = database2(conx, table_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried creating empty dictionary instead of a list, so that we can have table and record count (key-value pair)

```
table_list = ['tableA', 'tableB', 'tableC', 'tableD']

def database_1(table_list):
    dict1={'tableA':4, 'tableB':6,'tableC':7,'tableD':9}
    list1 = {}
    for table in table_list:
        count1 = dict1[table]
        # add = list1.append(count1)
        add = list1.update({table: count1})
    return list1


def database_2(table_list):
    dict2 = {'tableA': 12, 'tableB': 6, 'tableC': 7, 'tableD': 9}
    list2 = {}
    for table in table_list:
        count1 = dict2[table]
        add = list2.update({table: count1})
    return list2

def call_both():
    "compare the record counts from both for each table and log details of the comparison, not sure what to do here"
    first = database_1(table_list)
    second = database_2(table_list)
    print('database 1 values:'+ str(first))
    print('database 2 values:' + str(second))

call_both()
```

Output:
database 1 values:{'tableA': 4, 'tableB': 6, 'tableC': 7, 'tableD': 9}
database 2 values:{'tableA': 12, 'tableB': 6, 'tableC': 7, 'tableD': 9}

Now I need to compare two dictionaries

```
def call_both():
    "compare the record counts from both for each table and log details of the comparison, not sure what to do here"
    first = database_1(table_list)
    second = database_2(table_list)
    diff = DeepDiff(first, second, ignore_string_case=True, verbose_level=2)
```

Output: {'values_changed': {"root['tableA']": {'new_value': 12, 'old_value': 4}, "root['tableC']": {'new_value': 0, 'old_value': 7}}}

Comment: it worked for me, we can close the question